# How can I make all subindexes on multiindex to have same values

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a Dataframe with multiindex that looks like this:

```
a 1
  2
  3
b 2
  3
```

So The outer level has values a, b and the inner value is 1, 2, 3 for a and 2, 3 for b

I want to make sure that the indexes on the inner level are the same for all indexes on the outer level (in that case, create a new row for b with inner index 1). The values on the columns would be all Nulls for these new rows.

Is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can re-index with a `MultiIndex` made from your original dataframe indices:

```
df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels))
```

Example:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['a','a','a','b','b'],[1,2,3,2,3]])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(5), index=idx)

>>> df
            0
a 1  0.354691
  2  0.322138
  3  0.195380
b 2  0.731177
  3  0.912628

>>> df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels))
            0
a 1  0.354691
  2  0.322138
  3  0.195380
b 1       NaN
  2  0.731177
  3  0.912628
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks!